# PhP/HTML play button

Tags: php, audio

I'm wanting to make my own small webpage, I've got a domain [Saoo.eu](http://saoo.eu)
As you see there is a small play button in the corner witch plays a playlist. Is there anyway to have that playbutton on each page I'd add in the future without resetting every time the page changes?
Am I forced to use iFrames for that?

This is my player code

```
<button id="audioControl" style="width:30px;height:25px;"></button>
<audio id="aud" src="" autoplay autobuffer />
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#audioControl').html('II');
   if(Modernizr.audio && Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
    audio.setAttribute("src",'http://daokun.webs.com/play0.mp3');
} else if(Modernizr.audio && Modernizr.audio.wav) {
    audio.setAttribute("src", 'http://daokun.webs.com/play0.ogg');
}
});

var audio = document.getElementById('aud'),
count = 0;

$('#audioControl').toggle(
function () {
 audio.pause();
 $('#audioControl').html('>');
 },
function () {
 audio.play();
 $('#audioControl').html('II');
}
);

audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
count++;
  if(count == 4){count = 0;}
if(Modernizr.audio && Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
    audio.setAttribute("src",'http://daokun.webs.com/play'+count+'.mp3');
} else if(Modernizr.audio && Modernizr.audio.wav) {
    audio.setAttribute("src", 'http://daokun.webs.com/play'+count+'.ogg');
}
 audio.load();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Music on Website and Not Start Over?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26217/background-music-on-website-and-not-start-over)